# Styling sphinx LaTeX tables with booktabs package

Tags: tables, pdftex, booktabs, sphinx

I am trying to improve the look of LaTeX tables generated from Sphinx. In particular, I'd like to use the booktabs top, mid, and bottom rules and suppress vertical cell separators.

This rST table:

```
+--------------+---+-----------+
|  simple text | 2 | 3         |
+==============+===+===========+
|  simple text | 2 | 3         |
+--------------+---+-----------+
|  simple text | 2 | 3         |
+--------------+---+-----------+
```

converts to:

```
\begin{savenotes}\sphinxattablestart
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}[t]{JJJ}
\hline
\sphinxstyletheadfamily 
simple text
&\sphinxstyletheadfamily

 
2
&\sphinxstyletheadfamily 
3
\\
\hline
simple text
&
2

&
3
\\
\hline
simple text
&
2
&
3
\\
\hline
\end{tabulary}
\par
\sphinxattableend\end{savenotes}
```

I would like it to covert to:

```
\begin{savenotes}\sphinxattablestart
\centering
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}[t]{JJJ}
\toprule
\sphinxstyletheadfamily 
simple text
&\sphinxstyletheadfamily 
2
&\sphinxstyletheadfamily 
3
\\
\toprule
simple text
&
2
&
3
\\
\midrule
simple text
&
2
&
3
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\par
\sphinxattableend\end{savenotes}
```

I can load booktabs from conf.py.

The current Sphinx doc here https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html implies that this level of control is not available via conf.py, but there is a note at the bottom of the page that alludes to customization via templates:

> As an experimental feature, Sphinx can use user-defined template file for LaTeX source if you have a file named _templates/latex.tex_t in your project.
> Additional files longtable.tex_t, tabulary.tex_t and tabular.tex_t can be added to _templates/ to configure some aspects of table rendering (such as the caption position).

and there is a parameter for pointing to it which I have set as follows in conf.py:

```
templates_path = '_templates'
```

I added the templates from https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/3.x/sphinx/templates/latex

The templates are not read.

Questions:

1. Is this possible via templates and if so how? The feature was experimental in Sphinx 1.6 and may have been dropped.
2. If not, is there a way of redefining tables to use booktabs via the preamble, a sty file or otherwise?

Many thanks.

Comment: you could push the code for your table here so that it can be suitably modified -- do post a handrawn sketch of the required output

Comment: First off, you have to find out if the templating feature is still available in sphinx or not. That would be best asked at stack overflow or at sphinx development page. If it is, it will be easy to modify any template to use booktabs table features. Afterwards, you should provide any code, that could be used and tested upon (and if it is not pure TeX issue, at least add way how to compile or test it ...)